# What is return value of Locale.getDefault() if two locales are set?

Tags: android, locale, android-7.0-nougat

With `LocaleList` APIs, is there any rule on which of the added locales will be returned by `Locale.getDefault()` ?

Documentation for `LocaleList` mentions for `LocaleList.getDefault()` that - "The result is guaranteed to include the default Locale returned by `Locale.getDefault()`, but not necessarily at the top of the list." But it is not clear as to which locale will be returned by `Locale.getDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of ordering the locales by priority. Return value of `Locale.getDefault()`is the primary locale set on the device.